# Change shipping method based on payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a custom payment method whose shipping is calculated in a different way. If the user select any of the usual payment methods, he can choose any of the available shipping methods, but if he choose the custom payment method, all the available shipping methods must disappear and another shipping method will be available. I can't find any hook that trigger when the user change the selected payment method on the checkout page. What's the hook I must use to detect that change?

Comment: Your question is just too broad and too vague. You should search and try to make some code on your own before. Please remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. Additionally there are some existing plugins.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, my question isn't broad, I'm asking for the hook to do the specific task of my question, and isn't vague, I just need the name of that hook if it exist. I can't put any code because I only need a name, the name of that hook. I'm not asking for someone to code for me, I'm asking for that hook name. And a plugin is not what I need, I know how to code, I'm a Wordpress plugin developer. I'm just asking for the name of that hook.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec and thanks for the link, that's what I need.